# How to replace THIS non printable character type in a docx that represents a \n but Word is not recognizing as a \n?

Tags: char, docx, python-docx, python-re, non-printing-characters

I am parsing various .docx documents but the part of my code that splits paragraphs when it encounters "\n" is adding a new line when it encounters this weird symbol (circled in yellow):

[image]

could someone tell me **what non printable character is this and how can I replace it just with a normal " " space?**

(I can't just copy and paste it and use a replace() function because when I do, the char gets interpreted as a \n, but as you can see, if Word were really interpreting that character as an enter, it would've added the inverted P char insted of the weird enter sign (when I click on the show non printable characters button in Word), and it isn't. Hope I explained myself, thanks so much for the help!).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll find this character is a *line break*. In `python-docx`, the `str` value of `paragraph.text` represents a line-break with `"\n"`. You can have those mapped to a space (" ") instead using:

```
paragraph_text = paragraph.text.replace("\n", " ")
```